# There is a better way to get picture information on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I'm developing an application for Windows Phone 8 and I need to choose a picture from MediaLibrary. I'm using the [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) but the [PhotoResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photoresult%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) does't have information about the picture (like creation date).

I've tried to use the [File.GetCreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method but it gives me *UnauthorizedAccessException*

For now, to get the file creation date I'm using the following code:

```
{
    PhotoChooserTask chooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
    chooserTask.Completed += (obj, result) =>
    {
       if (result.ChosenPhoto != null)
       {
           String fileName = Path.GetFileName(result.OriginalFileName);
           String albumName = Path.GetFileName(
                                 Path.GetDirectoryName(result.OriginalFileName));
           //Get album by name
           PictureAlbum album = MediaLib.RootPictureAlbum.Albums
                                 .First(item => item.Name == albumName);

           if (album != null) 
           {
              //Get album picture by name
              Picture picture = album.Pictures
                                 .First(item => item.Name == fileName);
              if (picture != null) 
              {
                 //Do Something
              }
           }
        }
    };
    chooserTask.Show();
}
```

My question is, do we have a better way to get this information without iterate over all (worst case scenario) pictures in the album? Or Am I forgetting to setup some capability to 
be able to use the *File.GetCreationTime*?

Well, phone albums will not have millions of photos to iterate through but if exists a direct way to get this information I would like to know. :)

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into EXIF data. EXIF data are metadata that contains things like GPS coordinates of where the picture was taken, photo orientation, date taken, etc.

Search for ExifLib in NuGet. It will add you a Windows Phone compatible library that allows reading EXIF metadata.

Info about that library here: [ExifLib - A Fast Exif Data Extractor for .NET 2.0+](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET-2-0)

Comment: I knew about this lib but once I only want the creation date, for now, I was wondering if I could do it without a library. But it seems to be the only way to extract more information from a picture on Windows Phone. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using this [ExifLib](http://igrali.com/2011/11/01/reading-and-displaying-exif-photo-data-on-windows-phone/) for WP.